# simple react snippet is not generating functional component with const

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=burkeholland.simple-react-snippets) to generate code snippets when working with react.

In documentation it says when used `fc` abbreviation it should work as below.

```
fc - Function Component
const | = props => {
  return ( | );
};

export default |;
```

But, `fc` is not there only `ffc` is there which gives below snippet.

```
function | () {
  return ( | );
}

export default |;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is the most common one and propobaly what most of vsc devs use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets

Try this one with the `rafce` snippet....

Comment: It is still generating named function component not with const.

Comment: You misspelled I guess, it is `rafce`.

Comment: try "rafce" i think this is the one, @confusedWarrior is right

Answer (score 0):

ffc is for the functional component but sfc is for a stateless arrow function component. sfc will work in your case